# android asynctask mail send error

Tags: java, android, email, android-asynctask, jakarta-mail

i have a problem with AsyncTask. I want to send a mail but when i do with AsyncTasker i take "

> W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub
>   implementation.
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

error.

For sending mails i use this:

```
     class MailSender extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>
    {
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
         */
            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
                okuayar();
                Mail m = new Mail(email, sifre);

            String toAddresses = gmailler;
            m.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            m.setFromAddress("zekikelce39@gmail.com");
            m.setMailSubject("resim."+getFormattedDate(new Date()));
            m.setMailBody("Yeni resim çekildi.Tarihinde: "+getFormattedDate(new Date()));
/*
                try {
                    ZipUtility.zip(filename,"/mnt/sdcard/res.zip");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e("MailApp", "Could not zip folder", e1);
                }*/
            try {
               m.addAttachment(zipName);
               // m.addAttachment(filename);
                if (m.send()) {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Message sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    System.out.println("Message sent");
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Mail Yollandı",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    return 2;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MailApp", "Mail Yollandı", e);
                return 3;
            }

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result==1)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            else if(result==2)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else if(result==3)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "There was a problem sending the email.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Before Sending Mails i use zip function because i take picture from camera with Smartwatch and when i take picture from camera, i transfer pic. adress to arraylist, and wait for zip button to zipping all pics.
for zipping:

```
  public void resimadrescek(String Resimadress )
    {
        //Mail yollama aktif ise 10 resime kadar array içine alıp sakla daha sonra sıkıştırarak hepsini bir yolla.
        Resimdir.add(Resimadress);
        Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        testButton.setText("Bekleyen Mail Sayısı:"+resimsayi);
        resimsayi=resimsayi+1;
    }
    public void ziple(){
        String[] mStringArray = new String[Resimdir.size()];
        mStringArray = Resimdir.toArray(mStringArray);
       Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        zipName = "/mnt/sdcard/resim"+getFormattedDate(new Date())+".zip";
        ZipUtility zipManager = new ZipUtility();
        zipManager.zip(mStringArray, zipName);
        resimsayi=0;
        Resimdir.clear();
        testButton.setText("Bekleyen Mail Sayısı:"+resimsayi);
    }
```

And then for sending zip file to mail i use :

```
private void mailleriyolla(){
    File file = new File(zipName);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        new MailSender().execute();
}
```

Zipping function fine with no prob. But when i use Send function with asynctask i get error.
And logcat.

```
12-26 21:02:38.638  26745-26763/net.dheera.wearcamera W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
            at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:108)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:125)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:109)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
            at net.dheera.wearcamera.MainActivity$MailSender.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:565)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at net.dheera.wearcamera.MainActivity.mailleriyolla(MainActivity.java:122)
            at net.dheera.wearcamera.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:52)
            at net.dheera.wearcamera.MainActivity$1.onMessageReceived(MainActivity.java:110)
            at com.google.android.gms.wearable.internal.ax.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.wearable.internal.ae$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you Problem is this:

```
try {
           m.addAttachment(zipName);
           // m.addAttachment(filename);
            if (m.send()) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Message sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                System.out.println("Message sent");
                return 1;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Mail Yollandı",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                return 2;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MailApp", "Mail Yollandı", e);
            return 3;
        }
```

In this case you can not use Toast in a `BackgroundThread` even that you are not showing it there, but you are instantiating it. Move `Toast.makeText` out of `doInBackground` this will clear the Problem!

Comment: Nice answer. To be concise, you shouldn't perform any UI in doInBackground.